# remaining mouseover style until another mouseover

Tags: jquery

Hi
I want create an effect like below:

http://img27.imageshack.us/i/19466828.png/

There is a class in mouseover:

```
$(li).mouseover(function(){
$(this).addClass("newBg");
 });



 $(li).mouseout(function(){
 //
 });
```

But I want that "newBg" class remain until hover on the other "li" (not remove the class until hover another li). How can I do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$('li').mouseover(function(){
   $('li').removeClass("newBg");
   $(this).addClass("newBg");
});
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/PTQRM/

Comment: You should limit the selector in removeClass to only those that actually have the class: `$("li.newBg").removeClass("newBg");`

Comment: @Brandon there is no need to do that.

Comment: @Neal sure, the code works either way.  Its just an optimization to reduce the client cpu processing.

Comment: @Brandon, ok, whatever the OP decides

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw in my idea, though Neal's is a cleaner solution; there is more than one way to do this.

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mazzzzz/a2c42/10/